# Restcomm cluster: nodes list is empty in sip-balancer

Tags: voip, restcomm, mobicents, mobicents-sip-servlets

i'm trying to create restcomm cluster: sip-balancer + a few restcomm instances. But i can't connect restcomm node and sip-loadbalancer.

i used this tutorial - http://docs.telestax.com/sip-servlets-clustering-high-availability/ however haven't got any result.

Seems it should be 2 steps

1. change `path-name` attribute in
   `standalone/configuration/standalone-sip.xml`
2. add `org.mobicents.ha.javax.sip.BALANCERS` to
   `standalone/configuration/mss-sip-stack.properties`

as i understand node and loadbalancer use rmi as channel. i see(i used netstat) that server listens port 2000 and node establishes connection to it.

but when i try to use loadbalancer from sip client it returns "error 500 - no available nodes".
also i used remote debugged - nodes list is empty.

have i missed something?

p.s. i used docker restromm instance and sip-loadbalancer on the same machine.

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i have found my issue.

According to the log file on restcomm node - it can't connect to balancer by RMI.

Connection error is very strange - `Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1` and sometimes `Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1`

yesterday i tired to specify `java.rmi.server.hostname` but it did not help me

today i created small RMI client to balancer and it worked from my local machine(balancer is hosted on it too). however this app did work from virtual machine. so i added more logs to code and found:

1. app can lookup remote been
2. remote endpoint of this been is 127.0.0.1, but should be ip address of remote machine

After that i specified `externalHost` and `public-ip` for my sip-balancer and got bean endpoint address with `127.0.1.1`

so issue was found - ubuntu uses this *"local"* ip address for your "machine name".
you can find it in `/etc/hosts`.

sip-balancer(java application) gets it as ip address of endpoint for services

My fix is - `change 127.0.1.1 to 127.0.0.1` in `/etc/hosts`. after that sip-balancer provides real ip address of your machine for remote objects.

**Conclusion**: my issue - wrong operation system :)

**Common solution:** developer should check address type and don't use loopback addresses.

Comment: @jeand could you describe potential problems with operation systems in your tutorial?